# Angular 2 Typescript + JavaScript + browserify

Tags: javascript, typescript, browserify

I' trying to run browserify to combine all javascript and typescript files into one file.

```
var fs = require("fs");

function compileBrowserify() {
    var bundler = require("browserify")
            (["src/main/js/index.js", "src/main/ts/index.ts"], 
            { debug : true, cache : {}, packageCache : {}});
    bundler = bundler.plugin(require("tsify"), {
            noImplicitAny : false,
            target : "ES6",
            experimentalDecorators: true
        })
        .transform(require("babelify"), {presets : [ "es2015" ], 
            extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]});

    return bundler.bundle()
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.error(err.toString());
            this.emit('end');
        })
        .on('end', function() {
            console.log("Complete");
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("app.js"));
}

compileBrowserify();
```

The problem is that only the js files are making their way into the file. If in the inputs I leave only the typescript file, then the typescript files get compiled.

Any idea why?